# How to draw the graph using json data in HTML,CSS,JavaScript without any library

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, visualization

I need to plot a linear graph using json data. I am allowed to use only HTML,CSS and JavaScript. No libraries and api are allowed. Can anyone please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

json data:

```
var marks: [
    {
      "name": AAA,
       "age":20,
      "exam": {
        "no_of_exams": 5,
        "average": "400"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": BBB,
       "age":25,
      "exam": {
        "no_of_exams": 10,
        "average": "800"
      }
    },{
      "name": ccc,
       "age":30,
      "exam": {
        "no_of_exams": 8,
        "average": "700"
      }
    }
];
```

Now I need to plot for no_of_exams and average.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what exactly is failing. I'm afraid this question shall be flagged as "too broad to answer".

Answer (score -1):

First you need to create html `<canvas>` element where you graphic will be drawn. Then you can get the element using `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` by id, class or whatever. Then you can draw a simple shapes programmatically like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(10,0,20,75); // fillRect(x,y,width,height)
```

Passing your data from JSON file you can make rectangles filled with desired height and color. All is left - to loop throug all data and make some tweaking. Something like this

```
var colors = ['red','green','blue','purple']
for (let i=0; i<marks.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = colors[i]
  ctx.fillRect(marks[i].exam.no_of_exams,marks[i].exam.average,20,75);
}
```

You can refer [W3Schools docs](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_drawing.asp) to get mor information about using canvas

Answer (score -1):

the comment which is above is the first way of doing this but there is one more way:

Create div elements but resize them accoring to the JSON data and color them, you will get a bar chart if you use css properly. I think this is the basic method of making a chart. But careful about JS code performance.